# php curl_exec doesn't react to server response

Tags: php, windows, apache, curl, xampp

I'm trying to upload files to another server via Curl. The script uploads a file to my own server. My server processes the upload and responses, my script keeps going as it should. Hovever if the uploaded file is of a big (About 500MB) size (seems do differ) the script keeps running even after my server responded (AFAIK by logging the output of the serverside script). The client is a Windows 7 x64 machine running Xampp (different versions tried). If I upload the same file to the same serverside script via an html form everything works fine and I get my response. What could be the problem?

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        "MAX_FILE_SIZE" => "2147483648",
        "action" => "upload",
        "userfile" => "@".$filepath));

    if($uploadresponse = curl_exec($ch)){
          echo"Upload done!";
      } else {
        echo"Curl error no. ".curl_errno($ch)." (".curl_error($ch).")";
            }
```

Comment: I've now tried it from another machine, a server with Windows Server 2012 x64 (via Xampp not IIS). It worked. The reason might be that the Upload was 5 times faster than via my home connection.

Comment: With the same Xampp installation from the Win 2012 Server it didn't work on my home computer. I've also tried it in safe working mode with no luck. Firewall Antivirus and so on have been disabled since the very first beginning of testing. I will try it on another machine with a fresh Windows 7 installation. If it won't work I will try it on a Windows server 2012 installation at home since the problem may be the router or something.

Comment: It didn't work on windows server too. But it worked after I connected to my neighbours WLAN. I'll now take a look into the router settings.

Answer (score 0):

curl has a default timeout to allow it execute, regardless the success. You can extend this time using this curl option(as I am suspecting you are getting timed out while uploading a large file):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 * 60); // 5 minutes
```

Comment: I've just tried it, but the script still keeps running after the server responded.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set no time limit to `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` by simply setting the timeout to `0`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```